# ESlint for Sublime 3 not working

Tags: sublimetext3, eslint

I have searched extensively and tried appying various solutions but over 12 hours spent spanning 3 days and I can't seem to get eslint working for sublime. I have been on Stackoverflow for over a year now and seldom ask questions because most of the time I find an answer I can use or adapt, but this has me down.

Eslint runs well in the terminal, both in iTerm and standard terminal that comes with Macs. (I use zsh)

When I type "which eslint" in the terminal I also get the path:
/usr/local/bin/eslint

I followed the instructions on the Sublimelinter github page, including the troubleshooting, where I enabled debug mode, opened the sublime console, and loaded a js file.

When I restart Sublime I get the following message:

SublimeLinter: eslint linter loaded 
plugins loaded
SublimeLinter: debug mode: on 
SublimeLinter: temp directory: /var/folders/n7/qtc_6wdj03j98fg8ffvdjzwm0000gn/T/SublimeLinter3-Nick 
Package Control: Skipping automatic upgrade, last run at 2016-07-31 21:43:39, next run at 2016-07-31 22:43:39 or after

I get no error messages, or any messages, when I open any file, even a small example file with errors.

Am I missing something basic? Does it have to do with a path that I am not setting properly? (The latter would be my bet, but I have no idea where to start).

eslint -v:
v3.2.0

npm -v:
3.10.3

Thanks in advance!